How can I prevent separating 2 regex matches divided by a look-ahead?
I have the following regex to match things in the beginning of a text (optional), skip a part and then match the rest (optional again):
([A-Z]{1,3}[a-z]{1,3}\.\-?\s?)*(\s?\([A-Z]{2}\)\s)?([A-Z]{2}\s)?)?(?![A-Z][a-z]\s]+)([A-Z]{3}\s?)*

here a link to the regex: regex101
whose oversimplified version (note the look-ahead in the middle) is:
somestuff?(?![A-Z][a-z]\s]+)someotherstuff?

It works fine if I match either of the 2 or if I match none. If I match both using python, then they are actually 2 matches and not one:
regex = r"(([A-Z]{1,3}[a-z]{1,3}\.\-?\s?)*(\s?\([A-Z]{2}\)\s)?([A-Z]{2}\s)?)?(?![A-Z][a-z]\s]+)([A-Z]{3}\s?)*"

test_str = "Test.-Ing. (XX) Foo Bar YYY DDD\n"
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1): 
    print ("Match {matchNum}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, match = match.group().strip()))

This results in:
Match 1: Test.-Ing.
Match 2: YYY DDD

instead of:
Match 1: Test.-Ing. YYY DDD

What can I do to match both in the same match? I've tried putting () around everything, it didn't work.
PS: I know that it also matches empty strings.
EDIT some sample inputs and outputs:
Test.-Ing. (XX) Foo Bar YYY DDD
Test.Ing. Foo Bar
Foo Bar DDD
Foo Bar DDD YYY
Dr. Foo Bar
Test.-Ing. Foo Bar
Test. Foo Bar
XX Foo Bar
Foo F. Bar

The output is always everything except for Foo and Bar which are names, so they are pretty much always different and can have a single capital letter followed by a dot (F.), eg.:
Test.-Ing. (XX) YYY DDD
Test.Ing.
DDD
DDD YYY
Dr.
Test.-Ing.
Test.
XX
'None'/no output


Can you update your question with all "possible" sample inputs and exact expected outputs?

What exactly do you want to do? This regex is very complex, and usually that means it is better to split it up.

extracting the titles of people's names which can be in front of, after the name, both or not at all.

Why Test in the first output?

Because it was a wrong example, thanks!

An idea: Use one group for the prefix and one group for the suffix of the title. With re.sub replace to \1\2 to remove middle part: ^((?:\w+[.-]+ *)*(?:\(?[A-Z]{2}\b\)?)?).*?((?: [A-Z]{3})*$) (this is different to yours, just to illustrate). You will need to trim whitespace strip() from the lines.

Above example is for processing full lines from ^ start to $ end like your sample-input. For the variable middle-part I used lazy .*? to match as few as possible (satisfy group 2 suffix).

You can use non-capture group, even though the pattern can be simplified:
(?:(?:[A-Z]{1,3}[a-z]{1,3}\.\-?\s?)*(?:\s?\(?:[A-Z]{2}\)\s)?(?:[A-Z]{2}\s)?)?(?![A-Z][a-z]\s]+)(?:[A-Z]{3}\s?)*

This pattern is a bit more loose, if you want:
(?:(?:[A-Z]{1,3}[a-z]{1,3}\.\-?\s*)*(?:\s*\(?:[A-Z]{2}\)\s)?(?:[A-Z]{2}\s)?)?(?![A-Z][a-z]\s]+)(?:[A-Z]{3}\s*)*

There are many ways, the pattern can be more strict and cleaner. Given the limited info in your question, it is hard to conclude.
Code:
import re

s = """Test.-Ing. YYY DDD
Tesla.-Ing. YYY DDD
Test.-Inga. YYY DDD
Test.-Inga.                     YYY    DDD
"""

p = r"(?m)^(?:(?:[A-Z]{1,3}[a-z]{1,3}\.\-?\s*)*(?:\s*\(?:[A-Z]{2}\)\s)?(?:[A-Z]{2}\s)?)?(?![A-Z][a-z]\s]+)(?:[A-Z]{3}\s*)*$"

f = re.findall(p, s)
for found in f:
    print(found)


Prints
Test.-Ing. YYY DDD
Test.-Inga. YYY DDD
Test.-Inga.                     YYY    DDD

Note

That's not what I would like to do if your "Prints" part is correct. that just prints the same thing again and doesn't get rid of anything.

Can you just print exactly in the question, what the exact output should be for the provided inputs? @topkek

Sure, I forgot to insert the ```-s

@topkek It's best to write a set of algorithms to solve this problem. You can try writing regex, but you'll ran into test cases and the pattern fails. However, in case of algorithms you can easily define methods and exclude the edge cases. Simply split it first and then start writing your algorithms.

Maybe but that still doesn't answer the question. All the other cases work fine and this is my only issue which IMO is as simple as I described it in the original post.

@topkek Your defined inputs are fictitious. We don't exactly know what Test is. We can write some patterns that would work for given test cases, but I know from experience, it will fail later. For instance, dr. Alice M. McCarty-Jones, mrs. Alice M. McCarty-Jones, Ms. Alice M.N. McCarty-Jones, these are not in your inputs. But it could be. Some places, their names have more than 3 parts.

Technically you're replacing the "Foo Bar" with Empty String("").
So, your regex should be: r"Foo Bar"
Also it should match format like: Foo F. Bar
Hence update regex should be: r"Foo(\s\w+\.)?\sBar"

Now python regex replace format is:
re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)

So, your code should be:
import re

test_input_string = "Test.-Ing. (XX) Foo Bar YYY DDD"
print (re.sub(r"Foo(\s\w+\.)?\sBar", "", test_input_string))

But, this output contains extra spaces space start/end position or middle of the result. Need to remove the extra space or need to trim the output.
So, final code for appropriate expected output:
import re


test_str = [
  "Test.-Ing. (XX) Foo Bar YYY DDD",
  "Test.Ing. Foo Bar",
  "Foo Bar DDD",
  "Foo Bar DDD YYY",
  "Dr. Foo Bar",
  "Test.-Ing. Foo Bar",
  "Test. Foo Bar",
  "XX Foo Bar",
  "Foo F. Bar"
]

# re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)
for ele in test_str:
    print (re.sub(r"\s+", " ", re.sub(r"Foo(\s\w+\.)?\sBar", "", ele)).strip())


Sample Code: </>OneCompiler
Thank You..
